# Get Sitecore Item using lucene search by passing image url predicate value

Tags: c#, lucene, sitecore, sitecore8

I have a folder in sitecore8.1 that has a list of items under it. There is an image field in each one of them. I want to search for a certain item under this folder where image field value equals a certain value that I will pass using predicates - lucene search. Any idea how this could be done?

Thank you,

Comment: What do you mean with the "image field value"? What are you trying to find exactly?

Comment: I have a folder in sitecore that has a list of items, and I have an image with a name, so i want to look for the item that has this image name in its ImageField source value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should go with the following:

- Add a new computed field for image field
- In your code get the ID or the name of the image from that field
- Use this computed field to look for the item you need.